# how to create file .plist

Tags: ios, nsarray, plist

How to create a .plist file. What should be the data structure?

I tried this:

```
Story * story1 = [Story new];
story1.name = @"title";
story1.read = @"read total";
story1.callme = @"Tel";
story1.image = @"http://url image /0490_web.gif";
story1.details = @"content details";
```

platform  NSArray
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSDictionary for creating .plist file.
Read this Apple Tutorial for more details:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html

Comment: who told as, its much to use NSDictionary. Go with research before you give answer. @hoang

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableArray  *stories = [NSMutableArray new];

     NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"read", @"callme", @"image", @"details", nil]; // Set the key values for each field

    // Create a story dict and add them to the array
     [stories addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"title", @"read total", @"Tel", @"http://url image /0490_web.gif",@"content details", nil] forKeys:keys]];

     //If u need to add second details repeat the above step 
     // Saving .plist file

     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName.plist];
[stories writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: You cant able to write into mainbundle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689904/writing-nsarray-back-to-plist?rq=1

Comment: If you accept my answer, please upvote. It'll be use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
 NSMutableArray * ArrayDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

  ArrayDetail= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:story1.name,story.read,story.callme,story1.image, story.details, nil];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourPlistName.plist"];

[ArrayDetail writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Happy to help

Comment: If you have any doubt regarding this, please ask.